# Is someone who is a "Chief Medical Officer" in an American company also a "Corporate Officer?"

Tags: united-states, corporate-law, limited-liability-company

Is someone who the owner approved as the "Chief Medical Officer" in an American company, LLC, Corporation, S-Corp also a "Corporate Officer?"

Comment: As I understand it, there are job titles, and "Chief Medical Officer" is an example, and there are officers.  There is not necessarily a relationship between the two.  An officer has been specifically given certain responsibilities to act on behalf of the company in some capacity.  A CMO may or may not have that authority.  This question should be posed to the company's board or owners.  In many cases the corporation charter may spell out the roles and responsibilities of the officers.

Comment: That is going to depend on how that particular company is organized.

Answer (score 1):

In all likelihood, yes. A company has wide discretion to decide who its officers will be and what their responsibilities will be, something usually set forth in the bylaws or operating agreement of the company.

This said, the legal distinction between an officer, an employee, and an agent of a company is thin to vanishing. There may be isolated circumstances where there is a slight distinction, for example, in regard to who must have their connection to the company disclosed in certain circumstances, or as one factor in evaluating eligibility for being subject to a non-competition agreement or for opting out of worker's compensation coverage. But, for the most part, officers and employees have equal legal status.